# JavaFX detect changes of Stage screen location

Tags: java, javafx, window, stage

Is there a way in JavaFX to detect when the Stage/Window position is changed relative to the screen?

I can detect when resizing the Stage but not when the Stage is relocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`xProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#xProperty) and [`yProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#yProperty) of `Window`.

> The horizontal location of this Stage on the screen. Changing this
>   attribute will move the Stage horizontally. Changing this attribute
>   will not visually affect a Stage while fullScreen is true, but will be
>   honored by the Stage once fullScreen becomes false.

```
stage.xProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> System.out.println("X: " + newVal));
stage.yProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> System.out.println("Y: " + newVal));
```